# entering a cmd command with button click

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, cmd

im kinda a vba nub, and i am trying to launch Firefox with a button click based on [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5eng4H5ob0) (which is for visual-studio-2008) using the following code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
    Shell("CMD.exe")
    SendKeys.Send("start firefox")
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
    Close()
End Sub
```

however, all this does is launches `cmd`, it doesnt enter anything in it (when i type `start firefox` into cmd it works), what am i doing wrong?

note: i am using visual-studio-2012 (if it matters), and i have never used `cmd` before in a visual basic program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Shell("CMD.exe /C start firefox")
```

Comment: can you plz tell what if the command I am executing on cmd requires two ENTER key press from the user . Can it be done by passing ENTER key in my code. plz help.

Comment: @ParagGangil have you tried entering the SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}") command twice?

Comment: @Manny264 : Yeah I tried SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}" twice, but it doesn't work well. Instead I used "-y" after my command, which served the purpose very well.