# cmd call opening multiple cmd's

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, cmd

i have the following lines in a vb.net project im making

```
Private Sub yesButton_Click() Handles yesButton.Click
    Shell("CMD.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
    SendKeys.SendWait("start firefox")
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
    Close()
End Sub
```

i want the button click to open Firefox using `cmd` then close, it works however it opens 20-30 `cmd` windows and about 5 fireofx's in the process, why? and more important how can i prevent this?

i am running visual-studio-2012. this is ***not*** the same as [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970881/entering-a-cmd-command-with-button-click).

### --edit--

the same result is with this code

```
Private Sub yesButton_Click() Handles yesButton.Click
        Shell("CMD.exe", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus)
        SendKeys.Send("start firefox {ENTER}")
End Sub
```

Comment: To be honest, Whilst you're using Visual Studio, I'd put a breakpoint on the first line of that subroutine and then examine the Stack Trace under the debug menu, it might give you a clue why you're getting multiple calls. This sub itself looks fine to me, I believe your problem is external; its not being triggered by a Javascript mouse-over event is it ?

Comment: @RussC this is triggers by a button-click in a vb.net app thingy, and to be honest i understood like 10% of what you just said, im a javascript guy... i dont rlly even know visual-studio that well.

Comment: @RussC placed a break-point at the start of "SendKeys.SendWait" when i continue it tells me `changes are not allowed while code is running`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this

```
Shell("CMD.EXE /C start firefox")
```

this will open a cmd command window and start firefox. the `/C` parameter is used to execute the command string following /C and then terminates.

type `Run -> cmd -> cmd /?` to see full list of cmd parameters available.

Comment: thnx works perfectly. if you know y my version was giving problems i would love to hear.

Comment: it is because the button will be executed more than one time before cmd window becomes active and ready to read input keys. you can verify this by adding this code to the begining of button click: `Label1.Text += "Button1_Click @" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff") + vbCrLf`. To prevent this you can add this code `Threading.Thread.Sleep(200) : Application.DoEvents()` after `Shell` but before `SendKeys.Send`